Can I deploy my docker backend , node image and mysql image which will use docker-compose.yml to build container ON CHOREO?
I have created an docker-compose.yml file to create both my node and mysql images without using seprate database service .
version: '3'
services:
backend:
build: ./backend
command: sh -c "sleep 10s && npm run dev"
ports:
- '8081:8081'
depends_on:
- mysql
mysql:
build: ./mysql
restart: always
environment:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
MYSQL_DATABASE: db
ports:
- '3306:3306'
